# Get all roles - ASP .Net Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP .net MVC 2.0 web site and I am using the membership provider to store users and groups.

How do I get a list of all the roles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry got it

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()
```

Comment: you should mark this answered. There is no other answer to be had.